# Skip a command if it's taking too long

Tags: batch-file

I am using a third party exe to send emails from within my batch script. I have been testing my script on different machines and in one of the machines it gets stuck at send email command and doesn't proceed further.

I would like to add a check here if it takes too long to email me then i would like to terminate the command and proceed further in the script.

This script would be used on external client machines as well and i don't want them to be stuck forever with a message on cmd saying "Updating:"

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start your command in a secondary process and kill that after a timeout (I used `ping -t`, because that *will* "stuck"):

```
@echo off
start "MyStuckingCommand" ping -t www.google.de
timeout 10 
taskkill /f /fi "WindowTitle eq MyStuckingCommand"
```

Comment: Could you please explain the purpose of pinging google here? Also how can i suppress the output of the first line so that user running the script doesn't see it? and in the last line "WindowTitle eq MyStuckingCommand" what is this doing?

Comment: ok made it work by adding everything in one line `start \b "command" & timeout \t 10 & taskkill`

Comment: you can also ping `yahoo.com`if you prefer... No, seriously: I just had to use any command that would not end and `ping /t` was the first that came to my mind. *What*  to ping doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Consider Windows job objects. They allow to specify timeout (and other restrictions).

Comment: Thanks, not an expert in batch so seeking some help here.